# Heroku and Github integration (how to structure the project)

Tags: deployment, github, heroku

I'm creating a webservice and I want to store the source on github and run the app on heroku.  I haven't seen my exact scenario addressed anywhere on the 'net so far, so I'll ask it here:

I want to have the following directory structure:

```
/project
  .git
  README <-- project readme file
  TODO.otl <-- project outline
  ... <-- other project-related stuff
  /my_rails_app
     app
     config
     ...
     README <-- rails' readme file
```

In the above, project corresponds to http://github.com/myuser/project, and my_rails_app is the code that should be pushed to heroku.  Do I need a separate branch for the rails app, or is there a simpler way that I'm missing?

I guess my project-related non-rails files could live in my_rails_app, but the rails README already lives there and it seems inconsistent to overwrite that.  However, if I leave it, my github page for the rails app will contain the rails readme, which makes no sense.

Also ... I tried just setting it up as described above and running

```
git push heroku
```

from the main project folder.  Of course, heroku doesn't know I want to deploy the subfolder:

```
-----> Heroku receiving push
 !     Heroku push rejected, no Rails or Rack app detected.
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here's a simple solution that may or may not work for you.

- Create two projects on GitHub. One project should be just the Rails app (i.e. everything inside the Rails app directory). The other project should be everything outside the Rails app directory.
- Add the Rails app project as a git-submodule within the "container" project.
- Now you can add Heroku as a remote on the Rails app repository separately and push it to heroku. Heroku will accept the push because it is just a Rails app with the expected directories and files.

Answer (score 6):

A solution for the Heroku situation (not the README file):

If you're using the new [Heroku Cedar](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cedar) (I believe it wasn't available when you first asked your question) then your processes (like the rails server process) start up using [Foreman](https://github.com/ddollar/foreman). Thus, you can place a `Procfile` in the root github directory that looks like this:

```
web:     my_rails_app/script/runserver.sh
```

And then `my_rails_app/script/runserver.sh` could be a simple

```
#!/bin/sh

cd my_rails_app
bundle exec rails server -p $PORT
```

Locally, you should also create a file called `.env` (note the . at the beginning), which contains

```
PORT=3000
```

This file is read by foreman and used to set environment variables so that the port is set when you execute `foreman start` on your machine (from the root github directory, where the Procfile lies). The Heroku server takes care of the .env file on your dyno. The big advantage is you can set up multiple processes on the dyno that way!

Answer (score 4):

Just overwrite Rails' default `README` file. There's no reason to keep it around. Put your other project-management-related stuff in the `doc` directory. While you certainly have valid reasons for wanting to set it up the way you did, you're just creating a headache for yourself by  going against convention, and it's probably not worth the benefit.

Answer (score 0):

I would add everything underneath `/my_rails_app` to the Heroku git repository. Then add GitHub as a remote and add everything underneath `/project` to the GitHub repository. Then you can push the Rails application to Heroku (from `/my_rails_app`) and push the full project to GitHub (from `/project`).

Comment: You're basically saying create two repos, right?  One inside the other?  A good though.  However, I already tried that, and it doesn't work :). 

Github is the problem:  rather than displaying the my_rails_app as a normal version-controlled folder, it's displayed as a link to a git commit reference (in this case the first few characters of the commit id of the my_rails_app git repo).  So basically doing this renders github's web view useless for all intents and purposes.

Comment: You'll have to have two repos because Heroku requires its own. I have done this successfully with Heroku and GitHub, but not nested in this way. It looks like Justice might have a good answer.