# Is there an exclude file-equivalent for pushing in git?

Tags: git, github

I am using the exclude file to avoid my local settings from being overwritten when I pull a repository. I would like the same files to not be pushed when I push to the main repository. How do I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Exclude specific files when pushing to a specific Git repository](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2479162/exclude-specific-files-when-pushing-to-a-specific-git-repository)

Comment: I thought `.gitignore` do the job

Comment: Felix Kling ty, but I disagree. It's not about pushing, but pulling, and it's not about a specific Git repository. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a file is committed to your local repository (you did `git add <file>` and `git commit`) then if you push this commit to any other repository that file will be pushed too. You can push only whole commits, not individual files.

If you don't want to push this file, you have to first remove it, make a new commit with this file removed, and add it to .gitignore to avoid committing it again. So steps like this:

```
git rm yourfile
git commit -m 'Removing yourfile'
echo yourfile >> .gitignore
```

And you are done.

Comment: I think the question is about excluding files that are tracked, not about not tracking them.

Comment: It's been almost a decade, but considering that the author of the question accepted the answer suggests the answer addressed their problem.