# How to have README.md and LICENSE.md outside the src folder but still commit it to git in NetBeans

Tags: git, netbeans

Title says it. My README.md and LICENSE.md is currently in the Source Packages place, but then when I push it to GitHub, they are in the `src` folder instead of outside it.

How can I fix this?

Comment: I think, here's the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4293536/is-there-an-exclude-file-equivalent-for-pushing-in-git

Comment: @tijs But then it is totally excluded. I do not want that, I want it to still be committed/pushed, but outside the `src` folder.