# git - Is it possible to exclude file from `git push`, but keep them in the local repository?

Tags: git, version-control, repository

In my home directory I have files in a local git repository, because I want track them all under version control.

Most of these files I want to push to a remote repository, but a few I want to keep *in my local repository only* (they contain mildly sensitive information).

How can I achieve this with git? Can I configure a "`.gitignore-for-push`" file? I cannot use the local `.gitignore` file, because it would exclude these files completely from being tracked.

ps: I am aware of question [Is there an exclude file-equivalent...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4293536/is-there-an-exclude-file-equivalent-for-pushing-in-git), but the answer goes down the `.gitignore` path which I cannot use. The other question [Exclude specific files when pushing...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2479162/exclude-specific-files-when-pushing-to-a-specific-git-repository) answers only a specific case for git+heroku, not git alone.

Comment: I don't think so. You might be better off using a `git submodule` to keep your sensitive information away from the remote repository.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is not possible. If you have committed a file, then it will be pushed. The push action only acts on commits, not on a file basis.

But you could use a submodule for your sensitive data and keep this submodule on your local machine, while you push the regular git repository to the remote machine.

Comment: Yep, I suspected this beforehand. Interesting idea with the `submodule` - I will check it out. My current solution though uses a 2nd directory (see my answers http://stackoverflow.com/a/12019595/65889) - and with that it is kind of cheating, I know.

Answer (score 50):

You can go ahead and actually track these files (sans the sensitive info), but then use:

`git update-index --assume-unchanged <file>`

on each file. Then you can go ahead and add the sensitive info to each file, but Git will not see the file as changed, and not try to commit (and thus push) that sensitive info.

To get Git to update the info again, you'd use:

`git update-index --no-assume-unchanged <file>`

Comment: This has the downside that it wouldn't track changes to the file; but it is useful to know about the option.

Comment: I was looking for a way to ignore files locally without modifying the repository or the gitignore file (which would affect other people). I tried modifying the global git ignore config and this file under .git/info/exclude. Neither worked but this did the job. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

The way I eventually got around the issue is the following: Put the sensitive information in a sub directory with its own git repository and symlink the file(s) back to the old location.

E.g. in your home folder (`~`) lives the file `.creds` which you do *not* want in the public repository. Move this file in a sub folder called, say `protected` and create a symlink from `~` to `protected/.creds.` Of course, do not include this folder in your `~` repository , but create a *new* repository in the folder `protected` just to keep track of `.creds`. If you do not push this repository publicly at all, you are set.

I know this solution is kind of a cop out: My questions states that the file resides in the same directory, but the symlinking works for me.

Answer (score 6):

Here git-update-index - Register file contents in the working tree to the index.

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged <PATH_OF_THE_FILE>
```

Example:-

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged somelocation/pom.xml
```

[for more details.](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index)

Answer (score 2):

Might it be simplest to create a local branch, delete the sensitive files from that branch, then only ever push that branch to the remote repo?
If they rarely change, when you merge locally they should stay deleted in the new branch without asking you to confirm.
Plus having a branch specifically used for that remote push gives you a clear inventory of what you are pushing simply by looking at the file system contents without worry about whether a given file or folder is really a link or submodule etc.

Answer (score 1):

`git update-index --skip-worktree directory/fileName.js`

This would modify the index or directory cache. Each file mentioned is updated into the index and any unmerged or needs updating state is cleared.
For more reference, you can go through the following URL. https://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index

Comment: While it might be an answer to the question, it's best to explain what this command does. Code-only answers are generally not accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Just don't commit the files you want to exclude.

For example, if you have two files `a` and `b` that are in the local repo, but you only want to commit one of them, use:
`git add a` to add one of the files. Then commit with `git commit` (don't include the `-a` flag)

Comment: This will prevent the files from being under version-control at all, which is at best a bad solution for most configuration files, sensitive code etc. A `git submodule` is probably a better solution