# Removing files when merging

Tags: git

Is there a mechanism for removing files tracked in my repo when merging them to a different branch for pushing out to a shared repo? I know this alters the commit, and the hashes won't match, so I can't literally push my latest commit with some files missing. I'm more looking for a strategy to elide these files in a new commit on a separate branch in a somewhat automatic way.

One, cumbersome method I can imagine would be to merge to a cleanup branch, remove the files in a new commit there, then cherry-pick that to the shared branch. This wouldn't even be enough, though, as I'd have commits on the secret files scattered throughout my history. I'd have to filter-branch to remove commits containing them, or do a bunch of cherry-picking.

It doesn't seem possible, but I'll post the question anyway, in case there's something I'm not seeing.

Comment: are you trying not to push your secret / sensitive files to a remote repo?

Comment: Yes. These are simple things, like related notes and todo files that are just for me, but that I want tracked alongside the project to help me out in my own personal efforts, which shouldn't clutter up shared/remote repo(s).

Comment: the strategy to do that is keep the sensitive data in a submodule, check this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11895712/git-is-it-possible-to-exclude-file-from-git-push-but-keep-them-in-the-local)

Comment: @Atropo - Yeah, submodules is the best I've figured out as well, but then they're still "in" the shared commit. People just can't update it. That can get pretty messy. With git's model I guess the only option is a layer of indirection, wherein I start a containment repo that tracks changes to the main repo and to my secondary one, so they can live intertwined, yet separate. I'll have to think a bit more on it.

Comment: @kan - I had not before now looked into git notes. If they can remain tied to a particular branch, and thus not end up pushed, they might just work out. I work in Vim, and I have functions and mappings set up to let me toggle between files and their test/note/todo files. It might be possible to rework things to use git notes, if they work as hoped. If I figure anything useful out I'll add it in an answer.