# How to freeze local changes in git

Tags: git, version-control, repository

I have made some modifications to configuration files to run the project locally, and will never push these to the central repository.

Now, this makes the workflow annoying, as those changes are always present and restricts me to using handy shortcuts like `git add .` and `git checkout .` without commiting or reseting those changes, and the changes are easily lost by accidental command.

How do I make git to ignore these files locally from now on? First thing to come in my mind was to ignore them in *.gitignore*, but that just translates the problem to target *.gitignore* itself, and I'm concerned to accidentally messing up the repo.

How to freeze these local changes in a safe manner?

Comment: So, you still want to track these files but you wont be pushing them to the remote repository? Stick them in `.gitignore`, stage and commit your `.gitignore`. Done. You won't need to worry about these files anymore.

Comment: `.gitignore` only works for adding files - his config files presumably are already added, so `.gitignore` does nothing.

Comment: That's also no problem, `git rm --cached file.log` (here replace file with actual filename) , untrack these files and then add them to your `.gitignore`

Comment: @e.doroskevic did you even read the question? Your suggestion does the opposit of what OP asked about.

Comment: I'm certain this will ignore the files globally, when others fetches the gitignore

Answer (score 3):

The way to handle this is to take the (real) configuration files out of the repository. You can keep template config files inside so people have some kind of examples.

Alternatively, if you really want to keep the config files inside (do they have passwords in them?) you can create a directory for your config files, have a separate file per environment, and symlink them on each host. Then of course, you do not add the symlink to git (add the symlink to `.gitignore` instead).

Keeping modified config files around is a constant hassle (think about `git reset --hard`...) and will not make you happy in the long term.

Answer (score 0):

You can use use  `stash` to make your changes hidden away while adding or committing files.
when the new new updates are done you can apply the stash to your branch.
[Recommended Read](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Stashing-and-Cleaning)

Answer (score -1):

**Description**

If you want `git` to ignore files, add them to your `.gitignore`.

If these files are already tracked, you might need to untrack them before `git` can ignore them. For that you can run

> `git rm --cached <filename>.<extension>`

**Example**

```
git rm --cached development.log
```

For more information on how to go about your tracking issue. See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11895712/git-is-it-possible-to-exclude-file-from-git-push-but-keep-them-in-the-local).

Following instruction can be of assistance

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged <file>
```

`git` will not see the file as changed, and not try to commit (and thus push)

Comment: Did you even read the question? Your suggestion does the opposit of what OP asked about.

Comment: I did read the question. He asked how to ignore files locally. The above describes how to ignore them locally. The problem he faces with constantly maintaining files in `modified` state, is not easily avoided since the whole purpose of version control is to control the changes you make... Perhaps you could add a different solution to solve his problem?

Comment: No, because there is no solution except the one suggested by AnoE, hence I upvoted it. You suggested that he simply deletes the files from the repository while he said he needs to keep the files in the repository, hence my suspection that you didn't fully read the question. ;-)

Comment: I appreciate the input and I have done an edit the my answer above. It reflects the issue with constant `modified` state to a certain degree. I'd be happy if you could look over and see what you think.

Comment: Actually the `update-index` trick works, but it is highly dangerous and should never be used by the average user, but only from experienced Git pros that know what they are doing. You highly risk to f*** up your state with that in effect.