# Separate gitignore files for Heroku and GitHub?

Tags: git, github, heroku, gitignore

I have one file that is necessary for my heroku app but that I do not want in my GitHub repository.

Is there any way to have a `.gitignore` that is only used when pushing to GitHub?

Additionally, is there any other way that I can avoid pushing that one file to GitHub?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have already tracked this file, removing it (and even ignoring it in a `.gitignore`) before pushing to GitHub will *not* remove it from the history of that pushed repository.

That means it is important to know *why* you do not want that file on GitHub.

If it is for security reason, because it includes sensitive information, you might have:

- [more work to do](https://help.github.com/en/articles/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository)
- to externalize that file outside of any local repository to be sure it won't be included.

More generally, no, there is no conditional/separate `.gitignore` for two different remote repository.

In your case, you might have to script your git push operation in order to play with, [as in here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11895774/6309), to play with `git update-index --(no-)assume-unchanged <file>`.

Comment: Hmm, I think I may end up doing your second recommendation of hosting the file on a server or something like that. The reason I want it to be private is because it contains json credentials

Comment: @Mike Yes, hosting sensitive information *outside* a Git repository seems safer.

Comment: @Mike, Heroku would encourage you to put [credentials and other configuration in the environment](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars), not in your code.

Answer (score 1):

VonC's answer is good, but here's a bit more information.

> Is there any way to have a `.gitignore` that is only used when pushing to GitHub?

`.gitignore` never comes into play with `git push`:

- `git push` operates on *commits*, so if you want a file to be included in your Heroku build it must be committed
- Git's ignore system only prevents files from being tracked; it has no effect on tracked files

You could theoretically maintain a long-running `heroku` branch that's kept up to date with `master` (or whatever your main branch is) but also contains your Heroku-only file, but in my opinion there's no reason to jump through those hoops. Just include your `Procfile` or whatever it is in your main repository. What harm is it doing?

Note that if you had the *opposite* situation, where you wanted to omit some tracked files *on Heroku*, you could use a [`.slugignore` file](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/slug-compiler#ignoring-files-with-slugignore):

> If your repository contains files not necessary to run your app, you may wish to add these to a `.slugignore` file in the root of your repository. Examples of files you may wish to exclude from the slug:
>
> - Art sources (like .psd files)
> - Design documents (like .pdf files)
> - Test data
>
> ...
>
> The `.slugignore` file causes files to be removed after you push code to Heroku and before the [buildpack](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks) runs.