# Link Heroku commits to Github?

Tags: heroku, github, integration, push, commit

This may be a silly question, but when you commit to Git for Heroku, does it show up anywhere on Github or is there any way to have it show up that way? Or where are the commits being stored? I wasn't able to find anywhere online to know if this was possible or not. The closest and most relavent I did find on Stack was this:

[Heroku + Github Integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2454661/heroku-and-github-integration-how-to-structure-the-project)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if you push your code to github then you'll see the log messages - Heroku is after all just a remote git repo, just like github is.

Answer (score 3):

If you push your code to Heroku, it will not show up in Github unless you do the following. If you want to see your code in Github you must add Github as a remote repository along with your heroku repository.

```
git remote add origin https://git.heroku.com/repo.git
git remote set-url --add origin https://github.com/username/repo.git
```

Now every time you push your commits to heroku it will also push it to github

```
git push origin
```

Now when you click on the commit links in Heroku's Revisions tab, they will link you to Github.

Answer (score 1):

Github does not know this information as your just pushing new commits to heroku server.

However, you can locally view which commit heroku is on right now (assuming remote name is "heroku"):

```
$ git show heroku/master
```

Comment: anyway to push to heroku AND just add log info to github?