# How to set up and push to a second repo on Github

Tags: git, github, repository

I am a complete newbie in coding. I already have a repo on Github, for my project. Now I want to create a second project, and would like to commit it to github as well. I have researched a while and tried a number of ways, however, I can't seem to get it to work. Also, in the future, if I do create a second repo on Github, how do I push to the responding heroku app?

Can someone help, much appreciated.

Comment: check this SO question for similar problem solved: 
* http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3324586/push-from-github-to-heroku-without-downloading-repo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this SO question for similar problem solved:

- [Push from github to heroku without downloading repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3324586/push-from-github-to-heroku-without-downloading-repo)
- [Heroku and Github integration (how to structure the project)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2454661/heroku-and-github-integration-how-to-structure-the-project)

If you want to create a new repo on Github check:

- https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-new-repository